# how to disable page scroll in jscrollpane bar on mouse wheel move

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

Can any body tell me how to disable page scroll in jscrollpane bar on mouse wheel move. I just want that only a when there is a focus on  div using jscrollpane bar using mouse wheel move  when scroll ends in the jscrollpane div then page scroll should not be happen .
how to do this?